# BFF to Internal API with AAD / Entra ID B2C (.NET / ASP.NET Core / Identity.Web)

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-entra-id

I have a BFF and its API can be used by public accounts and I want to use Entra / AAD B2C for it.
The API/BFF should be able to access internal APIs which are using Entra ID / AAD.

My plan was to implement following flow with "on-behalf-of-flow" (OBO)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

I have two app regs, one in each tenant (B2C + internal). I made the internal app reg visible to the B2C tenant and gave the B2C app reg permissions to a dedicated scope from the internal app reg.

Public users authenticate against:

`https://<myb2cdomain>.ciamlogin.com/<myb2ctenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` with auth code flow with PKCE.

To get a token which I can use against my BFF I use a defined scope from the B2C app reg.

This works and I get a token.

Now I try to init an OBO flow to:

```
https://<myb2cdomain>.ciamlogin.com/<myb2ctenantid>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

or

```
https://login.microsoft.com/<myb2ctenantid>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

with the access token as assertion and the scope for the internal api.

The first gives me

```
AADSTS500207: The account type can't be used for the resource you're trying to access.
```

the second:

```
AADSTS500208: The domain is not a valid login domain for the account type.
```

I researched but I only found examples from Microsoft which are using the OBO flow for Graph not for own APIs. Additionally also I'm not sure if there is library support from Microsoft.Identity.Web for that.
There is the IDownstreamAPI package but I didn't got it to work and additionally I need to get it to work via HttpClientFactory and not with the IDownstreamAPI interface which makes it hard to use it together with other libraries. So I tried the flow manually first to ensure that it works and I setup everything correctly.

Happy for any hints or code samples.

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1353634/aadsts500208-the-domain-is-not-a-valid-login-domai and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/reference-error-codes#aadsts-error-codes

Comment: Can you confirm whether you have created b2c application by choosing "Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)" or "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant – Multitenant)" option?

Comment: So the first links says that this is because AAD doesn't do valid OAuth, correct? 

To answer your 2nd question: You mean the multitenant vs mutitenant with Xbox? I think the first, but not sure since you can only change to single tenant afterwards and this option disappears

Comment: Are you creating b2c app or Microsoft Entra app?

Comment: If Azure AD/Microsoft Entra app select "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)" option. In the Manifest just change signInAudience as AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount and try

Comment: A b2c application which should targets a b2c specific bff which uses some internal APIs.

I changed the signinaudience and now I get 
error_description=AADSTS500207%3a+The+account+type+can%27t+be+used+for+the+resource+you%27re+trying+to+access.
after the login.

Comment: it works without the b2c application specific scope but then I end up with a accesstoken with a nonce. And AFAIK these tokens are for accessing Graph & MS APIs and cant be validated by your own APIs.

Comment: If its a b2c app then the you have to select "Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256476/discussion-between-rukmini-and-pr177).

Comment: @Rukmini Thanks for the info you've shared here & to OP for posting the question I was about to surface. Is there an alternate location for AADSTS error code descriptions? I'm not finding anything for AADSTS500207 at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/reference-error-codes#aadsts-error-codes

Comment: @IdusOrtus  What exactly are you trying to do and in what context are you getting the error? You can post a new question with all the details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error ***"AADSTS500208: The domain is not a valid login domain for the account type"*** usually occurs if the application is not configured to authenticate the personal accounts.

Hence, register the Azure AD B2C application as "*Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)*" like below:

[image]

> **Note** that: As you are making use of OBO flow, Azure AD B2C doesn't support OBO flow.  Check this [**GitHub blog**](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/1994#issuecomment-1345695436)  by svrooij.

And hence you are getting the error *"AADB2C99075: The feature 'On-Behalf-Of' is not enabled for this tenant"*

As a workaround, make use of client credential flow on the Azure AD application or wire through the Azure B2C auth token and validate it in the internal API.

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:api://xxx/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

Comment: Its worth pointing out that with AAD OBO Flow is supported. With AAD B2C not and with Entra ID for customers you get the error with the domain. So currently there is no way of doing OBO Flow with a B2C version of Entra / AAD unfortunately. 

The mentioned workaround with using a M2M / Client Credential Grant Flow comes with a huge downside of loosing the signed user context in the called APIs.

Comment: Yes I agree with you client credential flow is non interactive flow (doesn't include user sign-in)

Comment: It is more than a bit aggravating and a bit asinine that Entra ID for Customers does not have the ability to do OBO!?!

The fact that when a user logs in and cannot access their own information through the Graph API is mind boggling.

I could maybe understand things for AD B2C given it's basically a hack, but the new Entra ID for Customers is supposed work like the normal one!!!!